# Excel: SUMIFS to sum values adjacent to text strings contained within a text string

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm hoping to sum numeric values with a multi-conditional, multi-array function that integrates wildcard searches into a reference formula.

My data is structured as in the excerpt at http://bit.ly/Xv8tHP

[image]

My objective for the formula in C2 is to:

- Sum values from $C$3:$C$24 in the "Price" column,
- for the rows in which $A$3:$A$24 = A2 ["New York" in this example], and
- for the rows in which the full text string in $B$3:$B$24 is found within B2 ["Digital TV" and "Basic" in this example].

The result to output to C2 in this example would be $80.95 from C24 + $38.99 from C3 = $119.94.

For the first condition, the following formula snippet works:
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$24,$A$3:$A$24,"="&A2,[...]

But I'm stumped when it comes to integrating the second condition, whether by using ISERROR(SEARCH[...])=FALSE, or INDEX, or another reference function. The 'contained by' part of the condition seems troublesome.

Does anyone have a suggestion?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
=SUMPRODUCT($C$3:$C$24,--(A2=$A$3:$A$24),IF(ISERROR(FIND($B$3:$B$24,B2)),0,1))
```

You must enter this formula as an array formula by pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> in the formula bar.  The array entry is necessary to make `FIND` take an array as the search text argument.

Answer (score 0):

Add another helper function to another column, say `E3:E24` containing formula

```
=FIND(B3,$B$2)
```

(this is case sensitive.  To make to non case sensitive use `SEARCH` rather than `FIND`)

Then the  `SUMIFS` formula is

```
=SUMIFS($C$3:$C$24,$A$3:$A$24,A2,$E$3:$E$24,">0")
```

Comment: Thanks! If I have multiple output cells like C2, as in the example at http://bit.ly/Wgix75 , what could be done to adjust this solution?